# drupal template.php not using tpl file

Tags: templates, drupal

I have a code which works on one server but not on the other. Basically we have written a template file which should be used if URL is discussion_forum but it shows page not found.

```
    /* discussion forum templates */
    $querystring=$_GET['q'];
        echo $querystring; // THIS PRINTS page-not-found
    $querystring=explode('&',$_GET['q']);    

if(!isset ($vars['node']) && $querystring[0]=='discussion-forum'){
    $vars['template_files'] = array(); 
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-discussion_forum'; 
}
if (!isset ($vars['node']) && $querystring[0]=='discussion_forum_answer') { 
    $_SESSION['question_id']=$querystring[1];
    $vars['template_files'] = array(); 
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-discussion_forum_answer'; 
    }

if(!isset ($vars['node']) && $querystring[0]=='discussion_forum_search'){
    $vars['template_files'] = array(); 
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-discussion_forum_search'; 
}
```

when I give page-not-found in place of discussion-forum in `$querystring[0]=='discussion-forum'`. It shows the the page properly. Don't know whats happening here. Its working fine on other servers.

Comment: Could you add where in template.php you add this? Is it in  preprocess_node, preprocess_page or something else? Just a tip, you can use the arg() function instead of getting the q querystring.

Comment: using it inside _preprocess_page(& $vars) {....tried with arg too. Even that is not working

Answer (score 0):

To add custom tpl I usually add the theme suggestions in the preprocess node.

```
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node____'.$vars['view_mode'];
```

So yours should be

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) 
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page-discussion_forum_search';
 }
```

It would help if you identify which version of drupal are you using because some of these things change between versions.